# extended class constructor not fired when child class is called using call_user_func_array

Tags: php, constructor

I have a quite strange issue and I don't know if this is due to `call_user_func_array` or not.

Testing on PHP 5.4

**Current setup**

I have, for example, an `AuthController` class that extends a base controller named `Controller`:

```php
class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function login() {
        return Response::json(array('error' => false, 'message' => 'I\'m in AuthController@login'));
    }

}
```

In the extended `Controller` class, I have a constructor that sets up, for example, a database connection (I have a var_dump + exit added for testing purposes):

```php
class Controller
{

    protected $db;

    protected function __construct() {
        $database = Config::env('database');

        var_dump($database);
        exit;
    }

}
```

Now to call the `AuthController`, I'm using `call_user_func_array`

```php
call_user_func_array(array($controller, $route['action']), $data);
```

**Now what should have happened:**

What should have happened is that `Controller`'s constructor should have fired, produced a dump on screen and exited the execution.

**Instead:**

Instead I'm actually getting the response from `AuthController`'s login method `Response::json()`.

The `Controller`'s constructor never gets fired.

I am having a difficult time understanding why it doesn't work since the PHP manual states that constructors get fired on every new object instance and if a parent class has a constructor and the child class doesn't overwrite it, the parent class constructor is called automatically.

Does `call_user_func_array` not fire parent class constructors autmatically or have I misunderstood something about PHP constructor entirely?

Comment: Where are you instantiating `AuthController`? What is `$controller`, an instance or the string `"AuthController"`? Have you overridden `__construct` in the child, or is it literally just what you show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a stab in the dark here, and say that you're actually doing this:

```
call_user_func_array(array('AuthController', 'login'), $data);
```

In other words, you're not passing an *instance* to `call_user_func`, you're just passing the string `'AuthController'`. That means your method will get called *statically*. If you had error reporting and/or *strict* error reporting enabled, you should see a notice warning you about calling non-static methods statically.

The problem is (probably) that you're never actually instantiating your class, so no constructor is ever run. `call_user_func` won't instantiate it for you. You'll need to do that yourself:

```
call_user_func_array(array(new $controller, $route['action']), $data);
//                         ^^^
```

Comment: Yes of course, I totally forgot to think that `call_user_func_array` calls it statically hence why it didn't work probably. instanticating the `$controller` variable with `new` solved the issue. Thank-you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

As PHP Document at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

PHP 5 allows developers to declare constructor methods for classes. Classes which have a constructor method call this method on each newly-created object, so it is suitable for any initialization that the object may need before it is used.

> **Note**: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to **parent::__construct()** within the child constructor is required. If the child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared as private).

**Example #1 using new unified constructors**

```
<?php
class BaseClass {
   function __construct() {
       print "In BaseClass constructor\n";
   }
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
   function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       print "In SubClass constructor\n";
   }
}

class OtherSubClass extends BaseClass {
    // inherits BaseClass's constructor
}

// In BaseClass constructor
$obj = new BaseClass();

// In BaseClass constructor
// In SubClass constructor
$obj = new SubClass();

// In BaseClass constructor
$obj = new OtherSubClass();
?>
```

Hope this will explain you about use of parent class constructor in child class.

also you can refere http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php , here they mentioned how to call parent class function in `call_user_func_array`.

**Example:**

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::__construct'), $args);
```

**Edit 1**

See below example:

```
class BaseClass {
    protected function __construct() {
        print "In BaseClass constructor<br />";
    }
}

//class SubClass extends BaseClass {
//    function __construct() {
//        parent::__construct();
//        print "In SubClass constructor<br />";
//    }
//}

class OtherSubClass extends BaseClass {
    // inherits BaseClass's constructor
    function test(){
        echo 'in test';
    }
}
call_user_func_array(array('OtherSubClass', 'test'), array()); //
// In BaseClass constructor
$obj = new OtherSubClass(); //produce fatel error
```

**output:**

```
Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method OtherSubClass::test() should not be called statically in /var/www/html/test/test1.php on line 22
in test
Fatal error: Call to protected BaseClass::__construct() from invalid context in /var/www/html/test/test1.php on line 24
```

So if string give in `call_user_func_array` function then it is producing out put but with strict standard error, and while creating new object of the class producing fatal error.

Comment: Hmm interesting, but my current use case seems to match your examples `OtherSubClass`. In my case `AuthController` is `OtherSubClass` that doesn't have a constructor, and only the extended "`BaseClass`" has a constructor defined. So in theory it should be inheriting the constructor right?

Comment: i think its due to `protected` constructor, try after changing it to public

Comment: The same thing happens with `public` constructor as well.

Comment: what does `$controller` have string or object? I think it is string

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the constructor is a special method called when a new object is created. [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) does not call any constructor because it doesn't create any new object.

```
call_user_func_array(array($controller, $route['action']), $data);
```

From your question I assume `$controller` is an object of type `AuthController`. It is already created at the moment when you pass it to `call_user_func_array()`. It's constructor was called when the object was created.

But wait a minute? What constructor? The class `AuthController` doesn't define any constructor. It inherits the parent class constructor that is `protected`. Because it is not public it cannot be called and the object is not created; the script throws a fatal error and exits.

You can either change the visibility of `Controller::__construct()` to `public` (this way both classes can be instantiated and the constructor of `Controller` runs for both). Or, if you want to keep class `Controller` not instantiable for some reason you define a `public` constructor for class `AuthController` that calls the protected constructor of class `Controller` to do the job:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // other methods here...
}
```

Comment: If the problem was a non-public constructor, PHP should fail with a fatal error because it can't call the constructor when trying to instantiate the class. It won't simply not call it, it will *fail.* It's much more likely that the class is never being instantiated at all.

Comment: A part of the problem **is** the non-public constructor. The poster didn't reach it because, as you said, they didn't instantiate any `AuthController` object.